# Slick Slider Arrows are cut in ios (iphone 8)but looks good when simulated in chrome and firefox

Tags: css, ios, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, slick.js

I have my slick slider here https://www.labtag.com/shop/product/clear-cryogenic-labels-for-frozen-vials-1-75-x-1-aha-224/(set for 4 slides on desktop and for 2 in mobiles(768px breakpoint)). Right now Slick Slider Arrows are cut (as shown in the attached image) in real ios device(iPhone 8)but look good when simulated like iphone8 or resized in chrome and Firefox. I'm right now in the windows environment and couldn't directly inspect the element. How to fix it?Thanks in advance[image: Arrows cut]

Answer (score 0):

a height of 60 px for the arrow solved the issue

```
.single-product div.product section.up-sells.upsells.products .slide-arrow{
    height:60px;
}
```